# How can I return a customized error message from a failed promise in a Google Firebase function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've made a Firebase cloud function to create a new user (I'm making a custom function and not using `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` because I want to add additional data for the user upon creation). I would like to show custom error messages when the promise is rejected, or at least retain the original Firebase error messages (in the event something happens like the email address is already in use, etc.). However, right now whenever the promise is rejected, the client can only see a `500 Internal Server Error`, which isn't of much help to the end user. I think this is happening as expected per the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference)

> If the callable trigger is invoked, but fails with an unhandled
>   exception or returns a failed promise, the request is rejected with
>   500 Internal Server Error, with an error code of INTERNAL. This
>   prevents coding errors from accidentally being exposed to end users.

Is there a good way to retain the original error messages in a cloud function without having it just default to a 500 error? I suppose I could write my own error handling in the `catch` block which would "resolve" the errors I want to show to the user, but that seems like a messy solution...any thoughts? My code is below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');
const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
adminConfig.credential = admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount);
admin.initializeApp(adminConfig);

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { name, email, password } = data || {};
        if (!name || name.length > 50 || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(email) === false || password.length < 8) {
            reject(new Error("Invalid data"));
        }
        else {
            resolve(admin.auth().createUser({
                email,
                password,
                displayName: name
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT -- The answer below solved my problem; here's my updated code in case anyone else has a similar need:**

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { name, email, password } = data || {};
        if (!name || name.length > 50 || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(email) === false || password.length < 8) {
            reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Invalid data'));
        }
        else {
            admin.auth().createUser({
                email,
                password,
                displayName: name
            })
            .then( res => resolve(res))
            .catch( err => reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', err.message || 'Internal Server Error')))
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) suggests that you should throw an [HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror) with the information to send to the client.  The string code will be translated into an HTTP status code, and the message you pass will be available as well.